# How can I register two dll:s in with the same macro using regasm in a nsis script?

Tags: dll, com, nsis, regasm

I am trying to register two dll:s using a macro that takes these parameters:

!macro RegisterWithRegAsm flag executable typeLib

I call the macro like this:

!insertmacro RegisterWithRegAsm "" "Dll1.dll" "Dll1.tlb" 
!insertmacro RegisterWithRegAsm "" "Dll2.dll" "Dll2.tlb"

THe problem is I can only run the macro one time cause the second time the NSIS complains that I have already declared a label :

inst__:
    StrCpy $R1 '$R0${DOT_NET_VERSION_2_SP2}\RegAsm.exe "$INSTDIR\${APP_NAME_COMPACT}\${executable}" /codebase /tlb:"$INSTDIR\${APP_NAME_COMPACT}\${typeLib}" /silent'

How can I move this label (and the u_inst_) outside of the macro so I can use it more than once?

ANyone know of a good site for reference? I have looked at the nsis web page but can't find references to multiple dll handling.

THanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to make the label unique with a prefix:

```
!macro UselessExample string
!define UselessExample_lbl "UselessExample_${__LINE__}" ;prefixing with the macro name is a good way to avoid conflicts
Goto ${UselessExample_lbl}pointlessjump
DetailPrint "Hello?"
${UselessExample_lbl}pointlessjump:
DetailPrint "${string}"
!undef UselessExample_lbl
!macroend

Section
!insertmacro UselessExample "Hello1"
!insertmacro UselessExample "Hello2"
SectionEnd
```

Or if you are creating a utility function that will be called in many places it is usually better to create a function. The CallArtificialFunction stuff in util.nsh is a helper macro that makes it easy to turn a macro into a function.

```
!include util.nsh

!macro UselessExample string
Push "${string}"
${CallArtificialFunction} UselessExampleWorker
!macroend
!macro UselessExampleWorker
Pop $0
DetailPrint $0
!macroend

Section
!insertmacro UselessExample "Hello1"
!insertmacro UselessExample "Hello2"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: I changed it to a function, since I want to be able to use it many times. Thanks for a thorough explanation!